# PHP won't save my file that's been edited in textarea

Tags: php, bash

I have a script to edit OpenVPN accounts (xxx.ovpn) from a dropdown list on my webserver, the script looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "</br>";
exec('ls /root/crt |grep -i -e .ovpn -e .txt',$list);
echo 'Config: <select name="config">';
$x=0;
while($x<count($list)){   
    if($list[$x]==$h[0]){
    echo "<option value=\"/root/crt/$list[$x]\" selected>$list[$x]</option>";}
    else{
    echo "<option value=\"/root/crt/$list[$x]\">$list[$x]</option>";}
    $x++;
    }
echo "<input name=\"edit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\"/><br>";

if(isset($_POST["edit"])) {
    $filename = $_POST["config"];
    $myfile = fopen("$filename", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $filecontent =  fread($myfile,filesize("$filename"));
    fclose($myfile);
    $nameonly = str_replace('/root/crt/', '', $filename);
    echo 'Showing: '.$nameonly.'<br><textarea name="akunvpn" autofocus rows="16" cols="78" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 9pt;">';
    if(isset($filecontent)) { echo $filecontent; }
    echo '</textarea><br><br>
    <input name="save" type="submit" value="Save">
    '; //echos file content in textarea.
 }

 //write to text file
 if(isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $save = $_POST["akunvpn"];
    exec('echo '.$save.' >> '.$filename);
 }
?>
```

The only part that isn't working is the save button, I tried with PHP (fopen, fwrite, perhaps I wrote the codes incorrectly) didn't work, and then I tried with bash also didn't work. Sorry I'm just a beginner in this so the possibility that I wrote incorrect codes is huge. The page looks like this: [image]

I want to save the file with the original name, the files are all located at `/root/crt` how should I fix this?

UPDATED: I closed the form `</form>` but still didn't work.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Close your form </form>

Comment: Well, that's the start ;)

Comment: `$list` seems to be undefined. Did you add error reporting?

Comment: use `file_put_contents($filename, $save, FILE_APPEND)` instead of `exec('echo '.$save.' >> '.$filename);` it's safer and will handle newlines/other funny characters better. you can also list the files in the directory without a shell command.

Comment: I added `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on line two after `<?php` but it gives me the following error: `Notice: Undefined variable: PHP_SELF in /www/test.php on line 3`

Comment: @Don should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` assuming it's available.

Comment: change your action to just `action=''` then. Could just be that, or as Mark said.

Comment: `Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /www/test.php on line 34` line 34 is: `file_put_contents($filename, $save, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: I changed the action to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and there's no error anymore on the form part, it's just that save button still doesn't work

Comment: @Don Please think these things through. Your error is saying the filename can't be empty. Why is it empty? Where did you define it? You defined it in the `isset($_POST["edit"])`. Does that run when you press Save? No, it doesn't. Therefore, $filename isn't being set, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "</br>";
exec('ls /root/crt |grep -i -e .ovpn -e .txt',$list);
echo 'Config: <select name="config">';
$x=0;

while($x<count($list)){   
    if($list[$x]==$h[0]){
    echo "<option value=\"/root/crt/$list[$x]\" selected>$list[$x]</option>";}
    else{
    echo "<option value=\"/root/crt/$list[$x]\">$list[$x]</option>";}
    $x++;
    }
echo '</select>';

echo "<input name=\"edit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\"/><br>";

if(isset($_POST["edit"])) 
{
    $filename = $_POST["config"];
    $filecontent = file_get_contents($filename);
    $nameonly = str_replace('/root/crt/', '', $filename);
    echo 'Showing: '.$nameonly.'<br><textarea name="akunvpn" autofocus rows="16" cols="78" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 9pt;">';
    echo htmlentities($filecontent);
    echo '</textarea><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'.$filename.'">
    <input name="save" type="submit" value="Save">
    '; //echos file content in textarea.
 }

 //write to text file
 if(isset($_POST["save"])) {
    file_put_contents($_POST['filename'], $_POST["akunvpn"]);
 }

 echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you that really works :D. Just curious, on the dropdown part, is it possible to keep the value selected when I hit the edit button? it always returns to the top value when I do that.